# AWS Copilot - why not use AWS_* environment variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-copilot

The [AWS Copilot documentation](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/credentials/) cautions about not using AWS_* environment variables:

> We do not recommend using the environment variables:
> `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` directly
> to look up your application's metadata because if they're overridden
> or expired, Copilot will not be able to look up your services or
> environments.

I have deployed a few testing apps with AWS Copilot, and I have used `aws-vault` in doing so. `aws-vault` gives me some short lived AWS_* environment variables (last about an hour). No issues so far.

What is this "application metadata" that copilot needs and how exactly does using `AWS_*` env vars cause problems accessing it?

Comment: Hello, there's many questions here with most having an answer online - can you please modify your question to focus on one?